# How to craft a nested loop statement to go back to a certain statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Hello I am having trouble with crafting this loop instead of it going back to line after I declared the "nameone" variable I want it to go back to either input '*' or a name I tried putting the loop before the input but it will come up with the error "referenced before assignment" which I understand why but I can't figure out a way to craft it to where it will let you enter a new name

```
def GetPosInt():

        nameone = str(input("Please enter a student name or '*' to finish: "))

        while nameone != "*":
            scoreone = int(input("Please enter a score for " + nameone +": "))

            if scoreone < 0:
                print("positive integers please!")
                break

            else:
                scoretwo = float(input("Please enter another score for "+nameone+": "))
                scorethree = float(input("Please enter another score for "+nameone+": "))

            testscores = scoreone + scoretwo + scorethree    
            avg = testscores / 3    
            print("The average score for",nameone,"is ",avg)

        if nameone == "*":
            print("no bueno")
```

## main

```
def main():
    GetPosInt()
```

Comment: If you want to keep re-asking for `nameone`, you need to have an additional loop outside in which you keep doing this, and only break this loop if you no longer need to keep asking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*...it will come up with the error "referenced before assignment"[...]*

This is because, you're likely specifying the condition to be `while nameone != '*':` but, not declaring `nameone` until you enter the loop. You can remedy this easily. Try this:

```
nameone = None

while nameone != "*":
    nameone = str(input("Please enter a student name or '*' to finish: "))

    ... # everything else remains the same

    if nameone == "*":
        print("no bueno")
```

Comment: Dude, you're freaking _everywhere_. Everytime I try to answer a question, you always beat me to the punch. Go do something else for while so I can have time to answer the question :-)

Comment: @ChristianDean Oh lord, that's the first time I've been cussed out for being _too_ helpful here. Welp, it's 4am where I am, I think it's time to call it quits for the day. ;0

Comment: I cursed? Sorry :( Where I come from, that's not really considered a curse word. Here's an upvote to make up.

Comment: @ChristianDean (cussed, not cursed) I consider `cussed = scolded`. Also, thanks! But I reached my rep cap hours ago, so I won't get that sweet +10. ;_;

Answer (score 0):

If what I understand of your question is correct then what you need is an outer loop.

Something like:

```
cont = 'y'

while cont=='y':
    # Do your thing

    cont = input("continue?(y/n)")
```

The code sample would be:

```
cont = 'y'

while cont=='y':
    nameone = str(input("Please enter a student name or '*' to finish: "))

    while nameone != "*":
        scoreone = int(input("Please enter a score for " + nameone +": "))

        if scoreone < 0:
            print("positive integers please!")
            break

        else:
            scoretwo = float(input("Please enter another score for "+nameone+": "))
            scorethree = float(input("Please enter another score for "+nameone+": "))

        testscores = scoreone + scoretwo + scorethree    
        avg = testscores / 3    
        print("The average score for",nameone,"is ",avg)

    if nameone == "*":
        print("no bueno") # I have no idea what that means.

    cont = input("continue?(y/n)")
```

Comment: The "no bueno" part was just set up to make sure that the command would work if I were to input "*" I am still currently working on it but your suggestion on creating an outerloop did solve my probelm thank you!